# Função similar ao imagecreatefrom para .doc/docx e pdf no PHP

Tags: php

Tenho procurado algo parecido para com a função imagecreatefrom, para documentos diferentes de imagens, como o doc e pdf, porém parece que não há algo do tipo. Atualmente eu subo os meus arquivos da seguinte forma:

```
$doc = $_FILES['arquivos'];
    $docs = $doc["name"];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($docs); $i++) {
        $tiposPermitidos = array('image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/png', 'doc', 'docx', 'pdf');
    $tamanhoPermitido = 1024 * 1024;
    $arqType = $doc['type'][$i];
    $arqSize = $doc['size'][$i];
    $arqError = $doc['error'][$i];
    if ($arqError == 0) {
        if (array_search($arqType, $tiposPermitidos) === false) {
            ?>
            <div class="fundo">O tipo de arquivo enviado é inválido! Arquivos permitidos: JPG, PNG, GIF, doc, docx, pdf</div>
        <?php } else if ($arqSize > $tamanhoPermitido) { ?>
            <div class="fundo">O tamanho do arquivo enviado é maior que o limite!</div>
            <?php
        } else {

            function create_ufilename($name, $path = '.') {
                $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $id = uniqid(rand(1, 100));
                $path .= '/' . $id . '.' . $ext;
                return is_file($path) ? create_ufilename($name, $path) : $path;
            }

            $img = $docs[$i];
            $diretorio = "../doc/";
            $tmp = $doc['tmp_name'][$i];
            $salvar = create_ufilename($img, $diretorio);
            $image = substr($salvar, 8);

            switch ($doc['type'][$i]):
                case 'image/jpeg':
                case 'image/pjpeg':

                    $largura = 500;
                    $altura = 300;

                    $imagem_temporaria = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp);

                    $largura_original = imagesx($imagem_temporaria);

                    $altura_original = imagesy($imagem_temporaria);

                    $nova_largura = $largura ?? floor(($largura_original / $altura_original) * $altura);

                    $nova_altura = $altura ?? floor(($altura_original / $largura_original) * $largura);

                    $imagem_redimensionada = imagecreatetruecolor($nova_largura, $nova_altura);

                    imagecopyresampled($imagem_redimensionada, $imagem_temporaria, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nova_largura, $nova_altura, $largura_original, $altura_original);

                    imagejpeg($imagem_redimensionada, $diretorio . $image);

                    break;

                case 'image/png':
                case 'image/x-png':

                    $largura = 500;
                    $altura = 300;

                    $imagem_temporaria = imagecreatefrompng($tmp);

                    $largura_original = imagesx($imagem_temporaria);

                    $altura_original = imagesy($imagem_temporaria);

                    $nova_largura = $largura ?? floor(($largura_original / $altura_original) * $altura);

                    $nova_altura = $altura ?? floor(($altura_original / $largura_original) * $largura);

                    $imagem_redimensionada = imagecreatetruecolor($nova_largura, $nova_altura);

                    imagealphablending($imagem_redimensionada, false);

                    imagesavealpha($imagem_redimensionada, true);

                    imagecopyresampled($imagem_redimensionada, $imagem_temporaria, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nova_largura, $nova_altura, $largura_original, $altura_original);

                    imagepng($imagem_redimensionada, $diretorio . $image);

                    break;

                case 'image/gif':

                    $largura = 500;
                    $altura = 300;

                    $imagem_temporaria = imagecreatefromgif($tmp);

                    $largura_original = imagesx($imagem_temporaria);

                    $altura_original = imagesy($imagem_temporaria);

                    $nova_largura = $largura ?? floor(($largura_original / $altura_original) * $altura);

                    $nova_altura = $altura ?? floor(($altura_original / $largura_original) * $largura);

                    $imagem_redimensionada = imagecreatetruecolor($nova_largura, $nova_altura);

                    imagecopyresampled($imagem_redimensionada, $imagem_temporaria, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nova_largura, $nova_altura, $largura_original, $altura_original);

                    imagegif($imagem_redimensionada, $diretorio . $image);

                    break;

                default :
                    move_uploaded_file($doc['tmp_name'][$i], $diretorio . $image);

            endswitch;
        }

            $sql_doc = 'INSERT INTO doc (docs)';
            $sql_doc .= 'VALUES (:docs)';


            $query_doc = $conexao->prepare($sql_doc);
            $query_doc->bindValue(':docs', $image, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_doc->execute();

        } else {
        ?>
        <p>Ocorreu algum problema ao enviar a imagem <?php echo $docs[$i]?>.</p>
        <?php
    }
   }
```

Essa função "imagecreatefrom()" cria uma nova imagem, limpando algum malware, caso exista, na imagem, certo? Tem como fazer algo parecido com isso em outros arquivos que não sejam imagens por questões de segurança? Afinal é possível o usuário injetar um malware em um arquivo pdf, doc e etc... e infectar o servidor, certo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade funções começadas em `imagecreatefrom` não limpam malwares, pelo menos nada disso é especificado na [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php).

Quanto a segurança, se alguém injetar algum código malicioso dentro de um arquivo de imagem ou algo assim, `imagecreatefrom` retornara falso pois o arquivo de imagem estará mal formado. Ainda que você salve a imagem ou arquivo usando `copy` ou `move_uploaded_file` sem usar `imagecreatefrom` em nenhum momento você precisa validar a extensão do arquivo. Você deve bloquear apenas arquivos com a extensão .php e afins que podem ser executadas pelo PHP.

Uma vez que o arquivo possui uma extensão, quando requisitado, o servidor vai buscar o mime-type do mesmo a partir de sua extensão e tentar responder de acordo. Nesse caso arquivos de imagem não executam códigos PHP.

Abra um arquivo JPG e no começo da primeira linha coloque  suba no servidor apache e tente acessá-lo através da URL. Provavelmente vai dar algum problema mas não vai mostrar a 'Hello'.

Comment: Valeu Matheus, eu tenho que dar uma estudada nessa parte de segurança, eu tenho um certo conhecimento já, mas não é muito aprofundado. Você sabe de algum lugar onde eu possa me aprofundar bem nesse tema sem ser na documentação do PHP? Eu cheguei a estudar um pouco sobre pentest, mas não me aprofundei muito.